# Death has a Theory?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, moksha, death

I saw in movie "Final Destination Series" that if you cheat death once, the next time you would die in a more brutal way? So, according to many websites, it is done by grim reaper. But would this be true from the perspective of Hinduism --- I mean is death there?? Can someone beat death??(Sorry about wrong tags!!)

Comment: Hades is a god in Greek mythology, not Norse mythology, and he doesn't have "followers" as far as I know.  And I'm not sure what "death and rebirth are one" is supposed to mean.  If it means that death is followed by rebirth, Hinduism certainly agrees with that.  But I don't know what Norse or Greek group of people you're referring to who also believe that.

Comment: Hades is the Greek, not the Norse god of death. The god of death in Hinduism is Yama.

Comment: Both the title of your question and the body are confusing. 'Hades followers believe that death and rebirth are one' - can you explain a bit more? I'm voting to close for now. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of Vaishnava branch of what you call "Hinduism", death is intrinsic to the material world we live in. It's not governed by any specific deity like "Grim Reaper" or whatnot.

This is directly written in the Bhagavad-Gita 2.22, 2.27, 2.18. Also, 2.20 is enlightening in this regard, too.

At the moment of death of your body messengers of the Yama-raja demigod will come to you to get you (the real you, not your body you lived inside) to the location of the Yama to decide on the punishment for all the stuff you really f*#ked up in your current life.

After the punishment ends, you'll be given the next body, according to what you thought of at the moment of death. And your next live will begin.

This is written in scrutinizing details in the Garuda Purana. It's relatively short, so I believe no link to specific shloka is necessary.

There's no way you can "cheat" or "beat" the death. It's completely absurd to think this way. The so-so comparison would be as if a single-cell bacteria would "cheat" or "beat" the Heisenberg's uncertainty principle.

Also, as a side note, it's not wise to believe to "many websites", as it's very easy to put information without any authority to the Web.